# Is it possible to get the record owner's name without code?

Tags: formula

In a case where we have Account and Opportunity object. From the Opportunity object, can we have a field that gets the Account Owner's Name without using a trigger?

I checked using a formula field and a workflow and the most that I can do in the formula is "Account.OwnerId". It won't allow me to have "Account.Owner.Name"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Effective Summer '13, you can accomplish this in a formula using the following syntax:

Account.Owner.FirstName & " " & Account.Owner.LastName

The syntax is a little different depending on whether the object supports Queues as owners, or just Users. For more information, see "Using the Owner Field" in [Tips on Building Formulas](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_creating_cross_object_notes.htm).